# Hide bottom toolbar of Grid Panel in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

How can I hide the bottom toolbar of **agentTypeGridPanel** ?

I tried `.getDockedComponent('bottomtoolbar').hide()` but its not working.

```
eci.admin.agentType.agentTypePanel = function(attributes){
    var agentTypeGridPanel = eci.admin.agentType.agentTypeGrid(attributes);
    var fieldsGridPanel = eci.admin.agentType.getFieldsGridPanel(attributes);
    var dataPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        itemId: 'eciAgentTypeDetails'+eci.admin.agentType.dataTypeId+'-panel',
        title : 'Agent Type',
        border : false,
        //height : 300,
        hideHeaders: true,
        items : [agentTypeGridPanel, fieldsGridPanel]
    });
    //eci.admin.agentType.GridPanel.getDockedComponent('bottomtoolbar').hide();
    //agentTypeGridPanel.getTopToolbar().hide();
    return dataPanel;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

`GridPanel.getDockedItems('toolbar[dock="top/bottom"]').hidden = true;`

You need to provide the grid code for further analysis.